# "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem in use Effect, just appears this message:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
   const loadStorageData = () = > {

      const storageUser =sessionStorage.getItem("@AuthFirebase:user");
      const storageToken = sessionStorage.getItem("@AuthFirebase:token");

      if (storageToken && storageUser) 
         setUser(storageUser);

      }
   };
   loadStorageData();
}, []);
```

I have tried numerous times to change the UseEffect, either by removing the useState or putting in a new parameter, but even after many searches the error remains

Comment: it's because useEffect is being called infinitely. try adding `[storageUser, storageToken]` to dependency list.

Comment: sorry but the error keeps repeating itself

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of useEffect appears correct. It should execute once when the component first renders (as no dependencies are defined). The update of state will cause the component to re-render but not execute useEffect again as its not the initial render.

It would be useful if you included all the code in the component as based on whats here it doesn't appear the useEffect is the issue.

Does the error still occur if the useEffect code is commented out?

If the useEffect is continually being called then something higher in the component tree is causing this or a parent component to be re-created. I would check what's going on in the parent component.